# Is it possible to trigger a link's (or any element's) click event through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some JavaScript code that needs to fire the `click` event for a link. In Internet Explorer I can do this

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.click();
```

But this doesn't work in Firefox, and I assume any other browser. In Firefox, I've done this

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
window.location = button.href;
```

I feel like this is not the best way to do this. Is there a better way to trigger a `click` event? Preferably something that works regardless of the type of element or the browser.

Answer (score 74):

http://jehiah.cz/archive/firing-javascript-events-properly

```
function fireEvent(element,event) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
       // dispatch for firefox + others
       var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
       evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
       return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else {
       // dispatch for IE
       var evt = document.createEventObject();
       return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
   }
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's usually better to check standard feature first (such as `createEvent`) and only then proprietary one (such as `createEventObject`).

Comment: Why negate the return value of `element.dispatchEvent()`? Both [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) and [`element.fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28VS.85%29.aspx) return false if the event was cancelled, otherwise true.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it, but you can call the onclick attribute of an HTML element as a method.

```
<a id="my-link" href="#" onclick="alert('Hello world');">My link</a>

document.getElementById('my-link').onclick();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally possible, afaik, mozilla has the [click()](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.click#1028373) method but for input elements only, not links.

Why don't you just create a function that the button will call on the onClick handler and, whenever you want to 'click' the button call the function instead?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has a stricter policy for allowed JS actions/events - I had similar problems with the click() event too. It's disabled on some elements to prevent XSS.

What is wrong with redirecting the browser? This sould work everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Hey, I don't mean to dig up an old thread - but I was searching for an answer to this same problem as well, and found a function new to jQuery 1.3x (I was having a problem with Ajax Loaded content)

Here's how I implemented it:

HTML

```
<a class="navlink" href="mypage.html">Online Estimate</a>
```

LOADED SCRIPT

```
$(".pagelink").click(function(){
    $(".navlink[href="+$(this).attr("href")+"]").trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

LOADED HTML

```
<a class="pagelink" href="mypage.html">Online Estimate</a>
```

The function is the 'Trigger Event'...
More details on it here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata

Comment: That won't work perfectly on every element 100% of the time. For example, it will not navigate to the value in the href, even if you have something there. Chris MacDonald's example **will** work on every element and trigger the default action, such as navigating to an `href` for an anchor tag.

Comment: That's very true. I'm using 'return false;', and bypassing the actual link element functionality, as I'm using jQuery and Ajax to load content into the DOM. In this case, it's the least amount of code and the cleanest solution - but in many other cases as pointed out by Dan Herbert, Chris MacDonald's would be the preferred choice.

Comment: jquery answer is irrelevant as the question is tag with javascript only. Reason why I voted down on your answer.

Answer (score -1):

i was searching for this one quiet desperately and the simplest one seemed to work!

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick();
```

it worked in chrome 7.0.5 and ie 8.0.6

Comment: This will only work if the onclick attrbute as been defined on the dom element!

Comment: Well you should try to provide a correct answer instead of replying with the original question!