# Linking i DIV, handing over the "geturl" event to the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so this is a bit complicated. I have something like this code:

```
<div> Hello, I'm inside a DIV, please <a href='foo'>click here</a></div>
```

And I want to bind a click event to the DIV that follows the link of the contained A. No worries, this I can do all by myself, but the only method I know of is using "top.location", which **bypasses the browsers normal handling of the link**

In a nutshell, if I do it this way, if I hold my **alt-key** pressed when I click the DIV, the link **won't open in a new tab**, which is the behaviour in my browser.

Any ideas what so ever to handle this? I can't pre-code this new tab/new window behaviour since its user-configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`$("a").trigger("click");`

To open it in a new tab, you could set an attribute `target="_blank"` before triggering the event.

Comment: Ok, I get "maximum call stack size exceeded" when I do that. See my example code here: http://sandman.net/test/hover_links.html

Comment: `$("li.list a").click(function(){ event.stopPropagation() });` seems to cause the problem `event is not defined: event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Your code to stop event propagation is needed. I've corrected it. 
`$("li.list a").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: Right, thanks - that removed the errors I got too. But the part of my code that does the trigger() part still doesn't work. Like 20 in my code is:

$(this).find("a.mainlink").trigger("click");

Upon clicking the LI, it does nothing...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javascr

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to trigger the browser's default handling of a link. The `click()` method (or jQuery equivalent) only runs the event handlers associated with a link; it does not follow the link, much less allow shift-click, middle-click, right-click-bookmark and so on.

To get the full behaviour of a link, you will need a real link. Wrap the contents of the following `<div>` in a new `<a>` with href pointing to the same place. Then if you need to, style the link so that it doesn't look like a link.

Comment: Right, but the problem with that solution is that it's not "legal" to nest links, and I really want to be able to have other links within the DIV, as you can see in my example link...