# JavaScript parent page redirection from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement parent page redirection from iframe. I know that it is impossible to do in different domains due to browsers security.
However I found that links have target attribute and tried to use it in the following way:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_top" id="testParentRedirect">someLink</a>
```

It works fine if I click this link manually, but I couldn't find cross-browser solution to simulate it using JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('testParentRedirect').click();
```

This works fine in IE, however Firefox and Safari don't know click function :).

I tried to work with jQuery, but for some reason they don't simulate click event for links.
(see [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-handl) post)

I couldn't find any appropriate solution on Stack Overflow.
Maybe someone could help me in it. I will appreciate it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger a link's (or any element's) click event through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javascr)

Comment: Oops, guys, sorry. I was wrong about setting location of the parent. It is possible to set it but it is impossible to get due to browsers security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in javascript to exit a frame:

```
window.top.location = "http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
top.location.replace( "http://google.com" );
```

in javascript to "escape" from the frame.

Edit: Using replace is slightly nicer, changed my answer to use that.