# JavaScript window.location does not set referer in the request header

Tags: javascript, html, referrer

I understand relying on Referer in the request header is not right. But my question is, why IE does not set Referer to the Request Header if I use `window.location`? Any thoughts or fixes?

**This does not set Referer in the Request header**:

```
function load1() {
   window.location = "https://" + serverURL + "/path/folder/page.aspx";
}

<a href="javascript:load1()">Link 1</a>
```

**While this sets**:

```
<a href="https://hardcode.server.url/path/folder/page.aspx">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried, go(), Navigate() or href? window.location does not navigate to a page, but simply redirects there.

Answer (score 40):

Your post title shows that you want to change the current page programmatically using JavaScript but still having the HTTP referrer provided (from what I understood, using a `<a>` tag is just for a test case).

You need to be aware of cross-browser issues:

- The HTTP referrer header (HTTP-Referer) is set when changing `window.location.href` under the following browsers:

  - **MSIE 9 (but probably any version above 9)**
  - Firefox (at least 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, but most probably all versions)
  - Chrome (at least 9, but most probably all versions)
  - Safari (at least 5, but most probably all versions)
  - Opera (at least 11, but most probably all versions)
- **MSIE (at least 6, 7, 8)**: the referrer is **not** set when changing `window.location.href` (this is why some pseudo-solutions are based on `myLink.click()`)
- **Firefox (at least 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)**: the `click` function does not exist (this is why pseudo-solutions based on `myLink.click()` do not work)
- **Firefox 5** : the `click` function exists under Firefox 5 but does not
  change the window location, so all the methods relying on the
  existence of the `myLink.click()` method will not work. Calling `myLink.onclick()` or `myLink.onClick()` raise an error ("onclick is not a function"), so [solutions based on these calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc) will not work.

In order to manage these cross-browser issues, I'm using the following method:

```
function navigateToUrl(url) {
    var f = document.createElement("FORM");
    f.action = url;

    var indexQM = url.indexOf("?");
    if (indexQM>=0) {
        // the URL has parameters => convert them to hidden form inputs
        var params = url.substring(indexQM+1).split("&");
        for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
            var keyValuePair = params[i].split("=");
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            input.type="hidden";
            input.name  = keyValuePair[0];
            input.value = keyValuePair[1];
            f.appendChild(input);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(f);
    f.submit();
}

navigateToUrl("http://foo.com/bar");
```

This solution works on all the browser flavors and version listed above. It has the advantage to be simple, multi-browser and easy to understand.
Note that this has not been tested under HTTP**S**.

Comment: This works great unless you want to use method="GET" and have url parameters in your url.

Comment: @Cixate : true for URL parameters (I edited the code), but I don't understand the argument for the form method since the default form method is GET.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't implying you needed the `method=GET` in the tag, was just saying that you couldn't use parameters in the URL if the form was using the GET method. But your hidden parameters fix works nicely.

Comment: This is probably obvious, (to all people except me) but if you run this script before page load you are going to get TypeError: document.body is null appendChild. So run it after the page has loaded :)

Answer (score 26):

Setting `window.location` is not the same as following a link on that page. It starts a new request for the page as thought the user typed the URL into the browser's address bar.

I did manage to locate a workaround:

```
function goTo(url)
{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    if(!a.click) //for IE
    {
         window.location = url;
         return;
    }
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
```

It creates a link on the page and simulates a click. The result is a change in `window.location` and the referrer is populated.

http://ianso.blogspot.com/2006/01/referer-header-not-set-on-http.html

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. $("body").appendChild(a) can be replaced with document.body.appendChild(a);

Comment: Thank you very much for doing so. I thought you were a heartless robot. :)

Comment: Seeing evidence that Firefox 5 returns true for a.click but does not navigate to the href when a.click() is executed.

Comment: "will not cause an A element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click

Comment: On Safari 5.0 running on Windows 7, this causes the following error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.click()')`.

Comment: @Zorayr: That was because I was passing `a` to `createElement` instead of `"a"`. I have corrected the code.

Comment: I am still having the same issue with `createElement('a')`. Any ideas?

Comment: Lovely! Another code-bloat hack to support Internet Explorer turd monkey. The only real solution for this is to wipe Internet Explorer off the face of the World Wide Web. The hack mentioned here does work in my case, however, Internet Explorer 8 displays a security warning, which the visitor must accept and then after the page is reloaded, the redirect to download a file works properly.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough points to comment on Evan's answer to suggest a correction so all I can do is post the correction here.  In short, `document.createElement(a)` is missing quotes and should be `document.createElement("a")` instead.  This should fix Kevin's concern about FF5 as well.

The whole function as I wrote it:

```
function goTo(url)
{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    if (a.click)
    {
        // HTML5 browsers and IE support click() on <a>, early FF does not.
        a.setAttribute("href", url);
        a.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    } else {
        // Early FF can, however, use this usual method
        // where IE cannot with secure links.
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

This works in our HTTPS environment with IE7, IE8, FF3, FF7, and Chrome.  So I imagine it works in FF5 as well.  Without this workaround we get 403 errors in IE7 and IE8 when trying to set window.location.  Regarding Sha Le's question as to why IE does this, I can only guess is that they believe it to be too insecure.  I had a similar problem with window.open in IE that I had to work around as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to trigger a link's (or any element's) click event through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javascr) uses a createEvent/dispatchEvent or createEventObject/fireEvent solution.

Answer (score -4):

Yeap, yours works as well, but ended up doing:

```
<a href="#" id="linkOne">Link 1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("linkOne").href = "https://" + serverURL + "/path/folder/page.aspx";
</script>
```

Comment: All this does is set the href of an anchor tag. It doesn't do anything unless the user clicks that link.