# Calling a URL handler from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension that finds phone number in our crm. Uptil now, it works. I can console.log it and it displays correctly.

We have jitsi softphone which has a URL handler configured. So, whenever I click any link with "sip:444@sipdomain", it fires jitsi and place call directly.

Is it possible to achieve that from my browserAction or simply call that from javascript without reloading the page?

Comment: One way that I could think of: create a link element with the number, then trigger click event. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and resolved the issue:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "sip:"+phone.val()+"@sip1.nomado.eu";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15164712/8648175