# How to fetch Google Analytics events and pagePath using the API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics to track outbound clicks from my website using events (e.g. [like these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302300/track-all-outbound-links-in-google-analytics?rq=1)). I create events like:

Category: "outbound"
Action: "click"
Label: [The URL that was clicked]

It's working fine - in the API dashboard I can have "Event Label" as the primary dimension, and "Page" as the secondary, and see the number of events.

I want to fetch the same data from the API. But in the API explorer, while I can do this to only get the outbound URLs:

```
metrics=ga:sessions&dimensions=ga:eventLabel
```

If I try to also get the page, I get no results:

```
metrics=ga:sessions&dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:eventLabel
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious (I'm new to the GA API) but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what changed, but now the same query works:

```
metrics=ga:sessions&dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:eventLabel
```

Although I *think* having `uniqueEvents` as the metric is probably more useful:

```
metrics=ga:uniqueEvents&dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:eventLabel
```

Comment: A comment describing why this is a bad answer would be more useful - I'd learn something! - than just downvoting it...