# asp-classic Not working Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am using Internet Explorer to run some code where I use javascript code window.open. Here is a sample code below. This is written in a page r_test1.asp

```
<script type="javascript">
window.open('r_test2.asp');
</script>
```

A window open naming r_test2.asp and there I am trying to get the referer. The code of page r_test2 is

```
response.Write(request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

The problem is I get referer in mozilla or chrome but not in Internet explorer which I need it badly there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer indeed does NOT pass a referer when you use the window.open event.

A nice alternative solution (to mimick a click on a hyperlink so IE does set the referer) has been previously posted here on StackOverflow:

[JavaScript window.location does not set referer in the request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762254/javascript-window-location-does-not-set-referer-in-the-request-header)

Comment: I've found it but thanks though. You are right and thanks for helping. But I still don't understand why there is a negative voting in my question. Is it not worth of a question?

Comment: the question was clear enough for me, so I also don't understand the downvote