# Javascript Redirect - Control It with Php

Tags: php, javascript, variables, redirect

Here is a script that i would like to use for redirection:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://yahoo.com">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
</script>
</form>
```

Now I have to control it with a php code, but this one doesn't work:

```
 $redirect = '<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://google.com">
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
 </script>
</form>'
```

I guess there is a syntax error, but I am unable to figure it out. Please help.

Also let me know is it an ok redirect method that keeps the script execution page as referrer?

Comment: That's some strange way to do redirection... why in the world would you want to do it like that while there's so many ways to redirect was it client or server side ?

Comment: The code syntax coloring above should be a big clue for you.

Comment: What @Bartdude said -- have you considered simply doing `<?php
header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
?>`

Comment: Because this is one of rare ways to keep referer from the redirect page, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `'` wrong inside `getElementById`

```
$redirect = '<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://google.com">
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
 </script>
</form>'
```

By the way, this is a unusual way of doing the redirect. Why not use `window.location.href` instead?

Or a [PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect?

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: I could but what referrer would be in the first case? I mean referer the destination page would see.

Comment: Seems like there are problems with the second method with referer passing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762254/javascript-window-location-does-not-set-referer-in-the-request-header

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to escape single quotes

```
$redirect = '<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://google.com"> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit(); </script></form>';
```