# Javascript + meta refresh keeps reloading

Tags: javascript

I have below code.But this keeps on reloading the page instead of redirecting.

```
    <script>
function my()
        {
          document.write("<meta content='0;url=http://google.com' http-equiv='refresh'></meta>");
        }
      </script>
      <center> <input name='image' onclick='my();' src='http://i.imgur.com/jgI5Ryt.png' type='image'/></center>
```

Note : i need meta refresh for some reason.So please help me with above code only.

Comment: rather than adding the meta tag just do `window.location = "http://google.com";`

Comment: you need meta refresh for some reason? What is the reason?

Comment: refresh is for **refresh**ing, keep it that way. Back in the time we had a language tag too that has been deprecated because of being misused.

Comment: The reason is , when i use the link http://t.co/Eq01WkzCRg?paramater in window.location i am not getting referral url as t.co.....

Comment: You probably aren't getting a referral URL because you are testing locally. Throw it up on a server or localhost and try...`window.location` works fine and is the correct way to redirect.

Comment: "Setting window.location is not the same as following a link on that page. It starts a new request for the page as thought [sic] the user typed the URL into the browser's address bar." Interesting information about redirecting and referrer url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762254/javascript-window-location-does-not-set-referer-in-the-request-header

Comment: nope...t.co sends the previous url as referral...but i want t.co itself as referral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by replacing

`document.write("<meta content='0;url=http://google.com' http-equiv='refresh'></meta>");`

with

`$('head').append('<meta content='0;url=http://google.com' http-equiv='refresh'></meta>');`

Comment: Meta redirects appear to be depreciated: "...users should not redirect users with this markup since [it] is non-standard, it disorients users, and it can disrupt a browser's history of visited pages." http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element