# Use Firebug command line to force click

Tags: command-line, firebug

I'm trying to use Firebug's command line to force a click event. This is as far as I've got and it's not very far.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('this_button').click();
```

Is is it possible to do what I want?

Thank you!

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one provided a solution so far.
What you are searching for is this:

```js
function simulateClick(element) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

For more info see [document.createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent).

I didn't try it in other browsers, but at least it work for me in Firefox 18.0.1.