# jQuery trigger doesnt work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, click

I'm trying to simulate click event on some element using jQuery when click enter in some textbox:

```
$("input[id$=txtbox]").bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
       SimulateClick();
    }
});

function SimulateClick()
{
    $("input[id$=btn]").trigger('click');
}
```

here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="checkUserPass_Click" Style="display: none" />
```

its not working on firefox. any ideas or work arounds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc

Answer (score 2):

`Trigger` won't work to simulate `click` event defined on `onclick` attribute on the `input` element.

You have to `bind` your function to the input in order `trigger` to work.

```
$("input[id$=btn]").bind('click', function() {
  alert("I am clicked :)");
});
```

And now, if you execute `$("input[id$=btn]").trigger('click');`. This will work.

Comment: but the click I want to simulate will fire a some function in code behind C#. btn is a runat server button.

Answer (score 0):

try using a simple html tag instead of asp control.
`<input type="button" id="btn" style="display: none;" >`

Answer (score -4):

This works on FF and other browsers, too.

```
$('input#btn').click();
```

Comment: Check which version of jQuery you use. The code works perfectly with jQuery > 1.2.6