# Trigger a link on a Anchor link with Javascript (without jquery)?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to trigger a click on a anchor link via javascript only (not Jquery - long story!).

We want to pass an anchor link's id into a function which will trigger the click, but have no idea how to trigger a click without jquery!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger a link's (or any element's) click event through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc)

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/902713/870729

Answer (score 2):

In some browsers, you can just do something like `document.getElementById(myelement).click()` (I'm fairly sure this is the case of IE only, but it could be available in more).

Since it's an `<a>` tag you want to click, its default click event can be emulated fairly easily:

```
function clickLink(id) {
    var tag = document.getElementById(id);
    if( tag.onclick) {
        var def = tag.onclick();
        if( !def) return false; // event cancelled by handler
    }
    window.location.href = tag.getAttribute("href");
}
```

Note that this doesn't take into account event added with `addEventListener` or any other events than the `.onclick` property and `onClick` attribute, and it doesn't open a new window/tab if the user Ctrl+Clicks or MMB-clicks.

Comment: What if the `href` is relative to the current page? Will `window.location.href = "/index.php";` still work?