# Background downloading with delayed saving to local drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

Using JavaScript I need to download a binary file in the background, then modify such binary data (some internal processing) and at the end to offer a client to save such file to a local drive.

Please advise what kind of approach should I use.

Comment: Serverside code, as you need to set the content disposition to get the file download dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process the data at client-side you can Base64 encode your data at the end and construct an A-element and provide a `data-uri` with MIME-type set for the `href` attribute.

To download the data you can use AJAX (either with jQuery or directly if jQuery is not an option). Showing [jQuery example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pageThatProvidesBinaryData.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
    processData(data);
});
```

(be aware of encodings when you deal with binary data).

Process the data, then you can use (html5):

```
<a href="data:my/mime;charset=uft-8;base64,<your-data>" download="Filename.ext">
Click to download</a>
```

Replace `my/mime` to actual types (ie. `application/octet-stream` for generic binaries).

Providing a `download` attribute for the `A`-tag will allow the user to download the data when link is clicked (if he uses a html5 enabled browser).

If you want this to happen automatically, you can hide the a-element and generate a click:
[Is it possible to trigger a link's (or any element's) click event through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143747/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-links-or-any-elements-click-event-through-javasc)

For details on data-uris:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: That seems to solve the end part of my task, when I will dynamically generate an A link and simulate a click on it... But how should I download the data before that to do an internal processing?

Comment: @Ωmega You can download data asynchronous in the background using either AJAX or WebSockets. For this use jQuery and Ajax is probably the best choice.

Comment: @Ωmega Updated answer with example