# Firefox Extension Updating Text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to set a textfield value in a webpage through Javascript/Jquery in my firefox extension, It updates the field value but it doesn't call the attached functions.

I've tried to execute following JS directly in my browser, it works fine but when I try to use same JS in my extension, it doesn't work properly.

```
jQuery("#deposit").val("100");
jQuery("#deposit").change();
```

the above code update the text field value but it doesn't call function which are bound to change event. Have you any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked the console for exceptions? checked with the debugger? jquery may have issues with the sandboxing used for content scripts

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160325/firefox-addon-cannot-trigger-click-event-of-any-kind/28162405#28162405) might be related